# can any one tell me how to use filters in find ()

Tags: java, mongodb

```
System.out.println("filtering using greter than");

 FindIterable<Document> iterDoc3 = collection.find().(Filters.eq("qty", 15));
         
 Iterator<Document> it3 = iterDoc3.iterator();
         
          while (it3.hasNext()) {
             System.out.println(it3.next());
          }
```

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/mongodb/mongodb-find-documents/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use this to achieve what you are doing:

```
BasicDBObject getQuery = new BasicDBObject();
getQuery.put("qty", new BasicDBObject("$gt", 15);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(getQuery);

while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

For more info please read go through Less than or Greater than clause [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/mongodb/mongodb-find-documents/#less_than_greater_than).

To use `or` query, you can use this:

```
DBObject clause1 = new BasicDBObject("key1", value1);  
DBObject clause2 = new BasicDBObject("key2", value2);    
BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
or.add(clause1);
or.add(clause2);
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", or);
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(getQuery);
```

replace `$or` in the above query with `$and` to use `and` clause in `find`

Comment: how to apply and ,or clause

Comment: @kdhilli I have updated my answer to include `$or` and `$and`, please check

Comment: how to perform joins in mongodb